# Problem compiling gnustep-gui-0.16.0 undefined reference to png_sizeof

Tags: objective-c, gnu, gnustep, openstep

I'm trying to compile GNUstep on a linux box but gnustep-gui-0.16.0 package is failing. I downloaded GNUstep Startup stable 0.20.1 (http://wwwmain.gnustep.org/resources/downloads.php)and follow instructions about how to compile (./configure && make). I'm getting this error:

`libgnustep-gui.so: undefined reference to 'png_sizeof'`

I have compiled latest libpng (1.2.34) and I can see that png_sizeof is defined as macro. However, I'm not quite sure how to fix the gnustep-gui-0.16.0 build. I tried to pass the include/lib directory where libpng is installed to configure build but nothing seems to help.

I have quite up to date linux box but using gcc 3.3 (upgrade is not an option - but this should not be a problem).

Full error:

```
Making all for tool set_show_service...
 Compiling file set_show_service.m ...
 Linking tool set_show_service ...
../Source/./obj/libgnustep-gui.so: undefined reference to `png_sizeof'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
gmake[3]: *** [obj/set_show_service] Error 1
gmake[2]: *** [set_show_service.all.tool.variables] Error 2
gmake[1]: *** [internal-all] Error 2
gmake[1]: Leaving directory `/home/bla/local/src/gnustep-startup-0.22.0/build/gnustep-gui-0.16.0'
gmake[3]: *** [obj/set_show_service] Error 1
gmake[2]: *** [set_show_service.all.tool.variables] Error 2
gmake[1]: *** [internal-all] Error 2
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I compiled with --verbose (or --debug ?) I noticed that the gnustep is looking into it's ~/GNUstep/System/Library/Libraries and Headers (among other places) so I moved a copy of libpng, that I've just recompiled, into that area and it all compiled without problems.

Comment: appears that png_sizeof was removed in version 1.6.0 of libpng https://github.com/glennrp/libpng/blob/libpng16/CHANGES#L4206

Answer (score 1):

Note that you can run `make messages=yes` to let GNUstep-make be more verbose about what it is doing.